# optimized tensorflow graph is slower than original on android

Tags: android, optimization, tensorflow, inference, darkflow

I have a tensorflow graph from [darkflow](https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow) on which I am running inference on an android device (on CPU Snapdragon 820). I found [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/#optimizing-for-deployment) graph transform tool to optimize the model for deployment. So I optimized my graph an expected to be faster than it was before, but it got slower by around 10%.

What can cause that? What am I doing wrong?

Here are the details:

- I use the [tiny-yolo-voc](https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow/blob/master/cfg/tiny-yolo-voc.cfg) model from [darkflow](https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow) without modification. I created the tf model like:

> $ ./flow --model cfg/tiny-yolo-voc.cfg --load bin/tiny-yolo-voc.weights --savepb --verbalise

- I optimized the graph with the following command:

> $ bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/transform_graph /
> --in_graph=../darkflow/darkflow/built_graph/tiny-yolo-voc.pb /
> --out_graph=../darkflow/darkflow/built_graph/optimized-tiny-yolo-voc.pb /
> --inputs='input' --outputs='output' /
> --transforms='strip_unused_nodes(type=float, shape="1,299,299,3") fold_constants(ignore_errors=true) fold_batch_norms fold_old_batch_norms'

- My code:

InfrerenceRunner.java:

```
public class InferenceRunner {

    private static final String INPUT_NODE = "input";
    private static final String OUTPUT_NODE = "output";
    protected final TensorFlowInferenceInterface mInferenceInterface;
    private final int mGridSize;
    private final int mNumOfLabels;
    private int mInputSize;

    public InferenceRunner(Context context, String modelFile, int inputSize, int gridSize, int numOfLabels) {
        this.mInputSize = inputSize;
        this.mGridSize = gridSize;
        this.mNumOfLabels = numOfLabels;
        mInferenceInterface = new TensorFlowInferenceInterface(context.getAssets(), modelFile);
    }

    public synchronized void runInference(Bitmap image) {
        Trace.beginSection("imageTransform");
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, mInputSize, mInputSize, false);
        int[] intValues = new int[mInputSize * mInputSize];
        float[] floatValues = new float[mInputSize * mInputSize * 3];
        bitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

        for (int i = 0; i < intValues.length; ++i) {
            floatValues[i * 3 + 0] = ((intValues[i] >> 16) & 0xFF) / 255.0f;
            floatValues[i * 3 + 1] = ((intValues[i] >> 8) & 0xFF) / 255.0f;
            floatValues[i * 3 + 2] = (intValues[i] & 0xFF) / 255.0f;
        }
        Trace.endSection();

        Trace.beginSection("inferenceFeed");
        mInferenceInterface.feed(INPUT_NODE, floatValues, 1, mInputSize, mInputSize, 3);
        Trace.endSection();

        Trace.beginSection("inferenceRun");
        mInferenceInterface.run(new String[]{OUTPUT_NODE});
        Trace.endSection();

        final float[] resu =
                new float[mGridSize * mGridSize * (mNumOfLabels + 5) * 5];
        Trace.beginSection("inferenceFetch");
        mInferenceInterface.fetch(OUTPUT_NODE, resu);
        Trace.endSection();
    }
}
```

MainActivity:onCreate():

```
...
tinyYolo = new InferenceRunner(getApplicationContext(), TINY_YOLO_MODEL_FILE, TINY_YOLO_INPUT_SIZE, 13, 20);
optimizedTinyYolo = new InferenceRunner(getApplicationContext(), OPTIMIZED_TINY_YOLO_MODEL_FILE, TINY_YOLO_INPUT_SIZE, 13, 20);
...
```

MainActivity:onResume():

```
...
mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Trace.beginSection("TinyYoloModel");
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                tinyYolo.runInference(b);
            }
            Trace.endSection();

            Log.d(TAG, "run: optimized");
            Trace.beginSection("OptimizedModel");
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                optimizedTinyYolo.runInference(b);
            }
            Trace.endSection();
        }
    });
...
```

- My Systrace output: 
  [image: Systrace]

TinyYoloModel wall duration is 5,525ms 
OptimizedModel duration is 6,043ms 
TinyYoloModel inferenceRun avg: 1051ms 
OptimizedModel inferenceRun avg: 1158ms

Do you have any idea why is the optimized model slower?

If you need more info feel free to comment! 
Thanks for your help.